# Custom Table using SQL query and php

Tags: php, html, mysql, html-table

I am trying to create a table from a sql query but I need to only have 3 results per table row.

I have a list of about 47 names so I have no problem printing them on a new line but how would I go about creating a table where the while loop would print a table row then print 3 table data cells with the query then create a new row for the next 3 values?

Exa:

result_1 | result_2 |  result_3
result_4 | result_5 | result_6
result_7 |  result_8 | result_9

Current While Loop:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {

      echo "<tr>";  
      echo "<td><input type='checkbox'> ".$row['name']."</td>";
      echo "<td><input type='checkbox'> ".$row['name']."</td>";
      echo "<td><input type='checkbox'> ".$row['name']."</td>";
      echo "</tr>";


        }
```

Database Structure:

id | name
1  | result_1
2  | result_2
3  | result_3
4  | result_4

Thanks in advance!

Comment: have you considered using nested for/while loops as you iterate through your query result to display your table? It would be helpful if you could post more code/db structure and other things that you have tried so far.

Comment: I updated the post with while loop code and database structure. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the modulus operator (%) to check if you're ready for a new line.

```
    $number_of_names = count($names);
    $number_of_columns = 3; //you can change this at any point

    echo "<table><tr>";

    for($i=0;$ i<$number_of_names; $i++){
        echo "<td>" . $names[$i] . "</td>";

        if ($i % $number_of_columns == ($number_of_columns - 1) && $i<$number_of_names-1){
            echo "</tr><tr>";
        }
     }

     echo "</tr></table>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try looping through the results using a for loop, then compare the remainder of dividing the iterator by 3, using the modulus operator.

```
echo "<tr>";
for($i = 0; $i<mysql_num_rows($result); $i++) {
  if($i%3==0) {
    echo "</tr><tr>";
  }
  $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)
  echo "<td><input type='checkbox'> ".$row['name']."</td>";
}
echo "</tr>";
```